# JavaScript, CSS, function not working in Internet Explorer Only

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, hover, jquery-events

I know this question has been asked a million of times before but for some reason I am still not able to find a fix/hack to the issue.

I have a simple JavaScript function

```
   //Robert Lindsay
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#robertLindsay").hover(function () {
                    $("#robertLindsay div").css("visibility", "visible");
                },
      function () {
          $("#robertLindsay div").css("visibility", "hidden");
      });
            });
```

and in my Body I call it this way

```
   <div style="margin-bottom: 51px">
        <div style="position: relative; float: left">
            <img alt="" class="style2" src="../Styles/12%20-%20065BHFgroup070.JPG" />                
            <div style="position: absolute; top: 5px; left: 150px; width: 131px;">
                <div id='robertLindsay'>
                    <div id="boxRobert" style="visibility: hidden; height: 127px; width: 150px;">
                        <center>
                            <a href="#">Dr. Robert Lindsay</a></center>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
     </div>
```

The CSS is simple:

```
 .style2
            {
                width: 650px;
                height: 410px;
            }
```

For some reason It all works fine in Firefox, Chrome, Safari except for IE (staring from 5 and above)

After Googling around, I found that the .hover action doesn't work fine for IE as the hover takes only the link `<a>` tag. Then I found a fix (more kind of a plugin) that tells you all the `.hover` functions will work fine but nothing happened.

I then changed my code to include some CSS and use no `.hover` JavaScript method

in the CSS

```
#show_div
{ position:absolute 
visibility: hidden
}
```

in the Javascript I had a simple show and hide method:

```
document.getElementById("div1").show();

else 
document.getElementById("div1").hide();
```

in the body I had:

```
<div style="position:absolute" onmouseover="div1" onmouseout="div1">
Show the piece of text or div here

</div>
```

But for some reason I am unable to do it for the image. I just can't hover over the image. If it is on the blank screen it works fine but if over the image I am just unable to get it working.

Could someone who fixed and had the same issue like mine help me through this?

Comment: *"After googling around, I found that the .hover action doesn't work fine for IE as the hover takes only the link tag."* You're confusing two very different things there. The CSS `:hover` pseudoclass only works on `a` elements in some older versions of IE. That has nothing whatsoever to do with jQuery's `hover` function, which works on all browsers jQuery supports.

Comment: Recheck the code you pasted, i didnt even work in chrome, some image" kept without any attribute and with missing double quote.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle link.

Comment: I have eddited the code now. Fiddle gives me this error "SCRIPT5009: '$' is undefined" Trying to figure out what the error is.

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder. I actually meant this "It works in Firefox, but since IE will only allow links to have :hover it will not work."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I was able to get things working finally ("All Browsers support this now")

my JavaScript function was

```
 function showlayer(layer) {
  var myLayer = document.getElementById(layer).style.display;
  if (myLayer == "none") {
   document.getElementById(layer).style.display = "block";
   } else {
   document.getElementById(layer).style.display = "none";
    }
 }
```

and in my Html body I called something like this

```
<img alt="" class="style2" src="../Images/whateverImange.JPG" usemap="#groupmap" />
<div id="myName" style="position: absolute; top: 500px; left: 450px; width: 225px; height: 50px; display: none;">
    <a href="http://news.google.co.uk/nwshp?hl=en&tab=wn">Show me Now and click me later</a>
</div>
<map name="groupmap">
    <area shape="circle" coords="100,100,50,100" href="https://play.google.com/store?hl=en&tab=n8" alt="" onmouseover="showlayer('myName');" />
</map>
```

and my Css was like this

```
.style2
 {
 width: 650px;
 height: 410px;
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 }
```

Oh God. Finally it works and so far my client has not had a complaint.

I always encourage to get more suggestions, as newbies like me get to learn a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might come from the css visibility rule, i'm not sure how it's handled by older ie versions. Try setting display:none/display:block instead.

Comment: You were right Jean-Georges. I had to also have a proper function in my JavaScript and call the right id. Now I feel this was simple and I complicated it.

Comment: Don't forget to validate the answer to close the topic ;)